# Groupby two line charts using seaborn or plotly in python with the help of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I have a data frame as shown below. which is a sales data of two health care product starting from December 2016 to November 2018.

```
product     price      sale_date       discount
   A         50         2016-12-01      5
   A         50         2017-01-03      4
   B         200        2016-12-24      10
   A         50         2017-01-18      3
   B         200        2017-01-28      15
   A         50         2017-01-18      6
   B         200        2017-01-28      20
   A         50         2017-04-18      6
   B         200        2017-12-08      25
   A         50         2017-11-18      6
   B         200        2017-08-21      20
   B         200        2017-12-28      30
   A         50         2018-03-18      10
   B         300        2018-06-08      45
   B         300        2018-09-20      50
   A         50         2018-11-18      8
   B         300        2018-11-28      35
```

From the above data I would like to plot month wise total sale price and total discount in a bar  plot for each products using in python.

So I would like to have two line plots for product A

```
X axis = year and month
Y axis1 = Total sale price
Y axis = Total discount price
```

The intention of this plots are to impacts the of discounts on sales.

Comment: Do you want a bar plot and also a line plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
df["sale_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["sale_date"])
df.set_index("sale_date", inplace=True)

new_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(by="product")[["price","discount"]].sum()).unstack()

#convert datetime to month-year format
new_df.index = pd.Series(new_df.index).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')

new_df.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(10,7))
```

Barplot:

[image]

Add `stacked = True` to `plot` in case you want a stacked plot!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['sale_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date']).dt.to_period('M')#Coerce date to datetime Month Year
df.set_index(df['sale_date'], inplace=True)#Set date as index



 df2=df[df['product']=='A']#Boolean select product A
 df2.groupby(df2.index).agg(PriceSum=('price','sum'), DiscountSum=('discount','sum')).plot(legend=True)#Groupby index and plot
```

[image]